Как сгенерировать колонку цифр в текстовом редакторе?
Примерно такую:
0
1
2
3
...
...
99999999


$ seq 0 99999999 > текстовый.файл

@aleksandrbarakin super

Если в WIndows, то for /l %a in (0,1,99999999) do @echo %a >> seq.txt
